# Создать массив с рандомными числами по возрастанию. php

Tags: php, массивы

Только в начале изучения php. Нужно создать массив из 10 чисел. В первый элемент записать число 1. Каждое следующее число генерируется случайно и записывается в массив при условии, если оно больше предыдущего.
Я знаю, что рандом может сразу выдать максимальную цифру, еще подумаю над этим.

```
$arr = [];
$arr = array_push($arr, 1);
while (count($arr) <= 9) {
   $num = rand(0, 100);
   $endNum = end($arr);
   if ($num > $endNum) {
    $arr[] = array_push($arr, $num);
}
}
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: А что вам мешает сперва сгенерировать массив случайных чисел, а потом отсортировать его элементы в порядке возрастания?

Comment: Упражнение именно такое. Я бы с удовольствием так сделала, т.к. гораздо проще. Но нужно именно генерировать случайное число и проверить, больше ли оно предыдущего. А потом записать в массив.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Но нужно именно генерировать случайное число и проверить, больше ли оно предыдущего. А потом записать в массив.*

Генерируйте случайные числа с постепенным увеличением максимального:

```
$arr[] = 1;
$total = 10;
$step = $total;

while (count($arr) < $total) {
    $rand = rand(1, $step + $total);
    $max = max($arr);
    if ($rand > $max) {
        $arr[] = $rand;
        $step += $total;
    }
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Только наверное в задании погорячились с условием "если оно больше предыдущего" нужно ещё учитывать, что случайное число может быть 100, тогда если текущее число 100 и предыдущее 100, то это будет бесконечный цикл. Поэтому я думаю вот такое решение может подойти, мы проверяем что предыдущее меньше текущего `$arr[$i-1]<$num`, если это не так, то повторяем попытку. Ну и добавочное условие, если случайное число оказалось 100, тогда мы записываем его `$num==100`

```
$arr = [1];
for ($i=1; $i<10; $i++) {
   $num = rand(0, 100);
   ($arr[$i-1]<$num or $num==100)?$arr[]=$num:$i--;
}
print_r($arr);
```